# Add song to playing queue in Spotify Desktop

Tags: windows, spotify, spotify-desktop

I'm trying to queue a song to Spotify Desktop (Windows 8.1) making use of [Spotify Remote Control Bridge](https://developer.spotify.com/remote-control-bridge-interface/). I want that song to be appended after the current playing track.

Due to the restrictions Spotify applies to this API, there's no public documentation and I can't get in contact with their developers. This is one of the posts I've been following to understand how this API works: https://medium.com/@b3ngr33ni3r/hijacking-spotify-web-control-5014b0a1a360

I've successfully played a song with `https://XXXX.spotilocal.com/remote/play.json?oauth=XXXX&csrf=XXXX&uri=XXXX`, but it jumps to playing queue instantly and replaces it entirely.

When I call `https://XXXX.spotilocal.com/remote/queue.json?oauth=XXXX&csrf=XXXX&uri=XXXX` it always returns "Method not implemented". Do I need a special Oauth token? Or CSRF token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just giving an update, you can now add tracks to a queue via a BETA endpoint.

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/add-to-queue/

I've tested it, and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: 2020 Update: I'm making this the accepted answer as now there's a proper way of adding tracks to the player queue

Answer (score 0):

#### queue.json endpoint

This endpoint appeared in their js-library, although it never worked and it's, like you said, not implemented. It doesn't matter which arguments you supply.

#### play.json endpoint

So, this endpoint is more interesting. First of all, in the past you could use the following parameter `?action=queue` to add a song to the queue, but sadly this doesn't work with the latest versions for whatever reason. The only thing you currently can supply is the play-context `?context`. A context basically tells spotify what to play **next** (like setting a new queue). So if you want to play a track of an album and simultaneously want the album to finish after the specific song ends, you can supply a `?context=spotify:album:albumid`. There is some more information about it in [this issue](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/pull/19) of my library.

Summarizing, you currently **can't add songs to the spotify queue**, but add your own context which will be used **as a future queue**

Although it would be nice to know why spotify isn't releasing any documentation about the local-API.